# C++11 : simple Tree implementation

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, c++11, tree, memory-optimization

I have created a C++11 implementation of a simple **Tree** for an online code challenge,

I'd like to know how to improve it and how to make my code use ***less memory*** :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>

template<class T>
class TreeNode : public std::enable_shared_from_this<TreeNode<T>>
{
    public:

        TreeNode(T data = T(), std::weak_ptr<TreeNode<T>> parent = std::weak_ptr<TreeNode<T>>());

        T getData() const;
        void setData(const T& data);

        TreeNode<T>& addChild(const T& data);
        TreeNode<T>& addChild(std::shared_ptr<TreeNode<T>> ptr);

        void removeChild(size_t indx);
        void removeChild(std::shared_ptr<TreeNode<T>> ptr);

        const std::shared_ptr<TreeNode<T> > findChild(const T& data) const;
        std::shared_ptr<TreeNode<T> > findChild(const T& data);

        std::shared_ptr<const TreeNode<T> > getChild(size_t indx) const;
        std::shared_ptr<TreeNode<T>> getChild(size_t indx);

        const std::weak_ptr<TreeNode<T>> getParent() const;
        std::weak_ptr<TreeNode<T>> getParent();

        void changeParent(std::weak_ptr<TreeNode<T>> parent);

        bool hasChild(const T& data) const
        {
            return findChild(data) != nullptr;
        }

        size_t getNumChildren() const;

        void print() const;

    private:
        T m_data {};
        std::weak_ptr<TreeNode<T>> m_parent { nullptr };
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<TreeNode<T>>> m_children {};

};

template <class T>
void TreeNode<T>::changeParent(std::weak_ptr<TreeNode<T>> parent)
{
    parent.lock()->addChild(this->shared_from_this());
    m_parent.lock()->removeChild(this->shared_from_this());
    m_parent = parent;
}

template<class T>
TreeNode<T>::TreeNode(T data, std::weak_ptr<TreeNode<T>> parent) : m_parent(parent)
{
    m_data = data;
}

template<class T>
T TreeNode<T>::getData() const
{
    return m_data;
}

template<class T>
void TreeNode<T>::setData(const T& data)
{
    m_data = data;
}

template<class T>
TreeNode<T>& TreeNode<T>::addChild(const T& data)
{
    m_children.push_back(std::make_shared<TreeNode<T>>(data, this->shared_from_this()));
    return *m_children.back();
}

template<class T>
TreeNode<T>& TreeNode<T>::addChild(std::shared_ptr<TreeNode<T>> ptr)
{
    m_children.push_back(ptr);
    return *m_children.back();
}

template<class T>
void TreeNode<T>::removeChild(size_t indx)
{
    m_children.erase(m_children.begin() + indx);
}
template<class T>
void TreeNode<T>::removeChild(std::shared_ptr<TreeNode<T>> ptr)
{
    m_children.erase(std::remove(m_children.begin(), m_children.end(), ptr), m_children.end());
}

template<class T>
const std::shared_ptr<TreeNode<T>> TreeNode<T>::findChild(const T& data) const
{
    for (size_t i { 0 }; i < m_children.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(m_children[i]->getData() == data)
        {
            return m_children[i];
        }
        auto find_child = m_children[i]->findChild(data);
        if (find_child != nullptr)
        {
            return find_child;
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}

template<class T>
std::shared_ptr<TreeNode<T>> TreeNode<T>::findChild(const T& data)
{
    for (size_t i { 0 }; i < m_children.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(m_children[i]->getData() == data)
        {
            return m_children[i];
        }
        auto find_child = m_children[i]->findChild(data);
        if (find_child != nullptr)
        {
            return find_child;
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}

template<class T>
std::shared_ptr<const TreeNode<T>> TreeNode<T>::getChild(size_t indx) const
{
    assert(indx < m_children.size());
    return m_children[indx];
}

template<class T>
std::shared_ptr<TreeNode<T> > TreeNode<T>::getChild(size_t indx)
{
    assert(indx < m_children.size());
    return m_children[indx];
}

template<class T>
const std::weak_ptr<TreeNode<T> > TreeNode<T>::getParent() const
{
    return m_parent;
}

template<class T>
std::weak_ptr<TreeNode<T>> TreeNode<T>::getParent()
{
    return m_parent;
}


template<class T>
size_t TreeNode<T>::getNumChildren() const
{
    return m_children.size();
}

template<class T>
void TreeNode<T>::print() const
{
    std::cout << m_data << " ";
    if (!m_children.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "(";
        for (const auto& child : m_children)
        {
            child->print();
        }
        std::cout << ")";
    }
}
```

[Test snippet online on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8ed2c2c1b728f6d)

Thank you in advance for your advice !

Comment: You know `std::map` or `std::set` are actually trees underneath the covers.

Comment: Yeah ^^ but here the goal is to create a tree structure from scratch, and anyway std::map doesn't give any access to its underlying tree

Comment: Not giving access to the underlying tree is the genius part that in my opinion you missed out in your implementation. People who use a tree don't want to know or manage the tree. That is why they are using a tree class. They want to use the tree to achieve something. For std::map its a container but that's not the only use of a tree. But users don't want to manage the complexity they want your class to handle all that stuff in the background without them knowing anything about the tree themselves.

Answer (score 7):

### Encapsulation:

My first question is why are you exposing `TreeNode`? Would the class that implemented a tree not be represented by `Tree` class? The `TreeNode` is an internal data structure that is completely private to the tree.

### Interface

My second question is what are you trying to achieve with the tree. What you are trying to achieve defines your public interface to the tree. Currently your public interface to the tree is the `TreeNode` which allows a user to directly manipulate the tree. This is **not** a good interface. User of your tree don't want to maintain a tree (that is why they are using your class so your class can maintain the tree and they don't need to worry about it). So what is your tree going to be used for, once you answer that you can define the user interface to the tree.

### Implementation

Why are you using `shared_ptr`. Is there really going to be shared ownership of nodes? A tree has a very well defined structure and there is no sharing of nodes each node has children (that are not shared but are owned) and a parent (which is shared but not owned).

So there is no need for shared pointers in the tree.

Are you exposing the `TreeNode` to the user of the class? That breaks encapsulation (exposing internal details of the tree). So that's not a good idea. Also your need to use `std::weak_ptr` is a result of sharing the structure externally (exposing implementation details). If you don't allow accesses to the internal structure you don't need to track if a node has references after it is deleted.

So at worst these pointers should be `unique_ptr`; but personally I would make them all simple pointers (as long as you wrap up the interface and hide the `TreeNode` from external users).

### Code Review

#### Copy Issues (Move?)

Currently your tree is not copyable or movable.

Copy I think is an issue.

```
TreeNode   root;
// build a tree here.

TreeNode   extra(root);
// Here extra has all the same shared pointers as root.
// If you modify root directly (by removing or adding a child)
// this is not reflected in extra.
//
// But if you modify the tree below the root node
// i.e. add/remove a node from a child of root then this is reflected
// in extra.
```

I am not sure this is a good idea.
A tree is an object that should be self contained (all the nodes are part of the tree). If two objects refer to the same tree then changing one should affect the other in exactly the same way.

Move only becomes an issue when you start encapsulating the tree as an object unto-itself.

#### Adding values.

You currently only support copying `T` objects into the tree. You may want to support both `Move` and `Build In Place`.

```
   void setData(T&& data);        // Move set
   template<typename... Args>
   vois setData(Args..&& values); // Build in place.
```

#### Printing Idioms in C++

I would change the `print()` to take a stream as a parameter (rather than default to `std::cout`. Then I would add `operator<<` so you can rint it using normal C++ idioms.

```
 void print(std::ostream& = std::cout) const;
 friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, TreeNode const& data)
 {
     data.print(str);
     return str;
 }
```